# stepper work only pressed by twice?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistepper

I an using a stepper to control the font size of a text view, but there is no action being fired until I press the stepper twice. Why is this happening?

The following code is for the `mystepper' IBAction:

```
- (IBAction) changeFontSize:(id)sender
{
    [myStepper setMinimumValue:14.0]
    self.myStepper.maximumValue =20.0;

    CGFloat newSize = [myTextView fontWithSize:self.stepper.value];
    self.myTextView.font = newSize;
}
```

Comment: check this http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/using-the-stepper-control-in-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

Check whether u had connected the `UIStepper` Recieved Actions to the `changeFontSize:` function for `Values Changed` not for `Touches inside`

Comment: I find the problem is that i need set the current value of stepper equals to minimumvalue. However, I want the value of size can pass through in muiltple scences so that the fontSize doesn't need to be press overtime. How can i get it???

Comment: @SteveLai, be more specific, I can't understand

Comment: Let say, There is 3 ViewController and there is a textView in each ViewController. I want to change all textView Size by pressing the stepper one time.

Comment: then u have to set a global integer value in ur prjct and set the value of stepper to that integer and use it in all viewcontrollers by setting the minimum value of stepper and set the fontsize of the corresponded text view to that integer